# How can I calculate the total number of timestamps for a given ID and code in Hive

Tags: hadoop, hive, aggregate-functions

We have code and products across different domains. We are tracking different timestamps at which the products transmit data. This how my data looks:

```
|     timestamp_s     |      Product | Code              | _c3  |
| 2017-01-01 01:18:04.40736  | A  | 119                  | 1    |
| 2017-01-01 01:18:05.20419  | A  | 119                  | 1    |
| 2017-01-01 01:18:11.21268  | A  | 119                  | 1    |
| 2017-01-01 10:48:22.52147  | A  | 119                  | 1    |
```

I want to find the total timestamps recorded for a product and code across different timestamps. Meaning like in the above case, the output count of timestamps for 2017-01-01 should be 4 for a unique product A and code 119 combination.

Basically, I want to see the total number of timestamp records for each day (meaning, the total count of all timestamp record(s) for 2017-01-01 as in the above case).

Comment: the output should be just single line for your data example?

Comment: So you want to group by (Product, Code, date) and count the number of timestamps, correct? What have you tried so far?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Use simple groupby+count distinct:

```
select count(distinct timestamp_s) ts_count, Product, Code
from table_name
group by Product, Code
```

Or if you need to have additional column with count on the same grain (without group by) use analytic function:

```
select timestamp_s, count(distinct timestamp_s) over(partition by Product, Code) ts_count, Product, Code
from table_name
```

Comment: Can you please explain the ts_count?

Comment: @BenhailMuthyala ts_count is a result column name, you can name it as you want